# SSL certificate warning error for a website running on http and https

Tags: ssl, certificate, https, ssl-certificate

We have the website which is running on both http(80) and https (443).

We purchased the SSL certificate and installed. It is working well for the web sites running only on https.

If we access the web site which is working on http as well as https using the correct certificate then we are getting SSL certificate warning error message.

What is the reason for this error? How to resolve it?

Details of the Certificate

Wild Card Certificate : *.example.com
Also certificate is applicable for :example.com

No warning error for
foo.example.com  - which is running only on https
abc.example.com  - which is running on both http and https service. This one shows the warning message.

This error comes in Chrome Browser. I tested it in Android Operating System.

Comment: What error message you got in your server error log while accessing? .Does the error shows on all web browsers ?

Comment: What error appears when it isn't working... your browser will display the warning

Comment: Chrome shows this error. Mostly on mobile browsers. The same browser is not showing any error if the web sites are having only http with the same certificate

Comment: Access through http does not require a certificate, you require only for https. So it will not show any error for http. Find any error log on server side while accessing through https.

Comment: You need to put up a picture of the browser error if you can't write the actual error being displayed... your description/question body doesn't give us anything to help you with

Comment: I will posting the error message in a minute

Comment: Error message is now posted

Comment: From the error message, I under stand that ssl certificate not mathcing with browser access. There are couple of reason for this. Is this a wildcard certificate or is it only for parent domain ? Is there any time issue, wrong time setting in the server ?

Comment: It is wild card certificate. There is no problem with time setting in the server. If it is time setting then the same error should be displayed for other sites running on same machine.

Comment: Getting a certificate warning on a http connection makes no sense.  Can you edit your question to include more specifics about the browser and OS you are using?

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: You may need to install some intermediate certificates so that Android can verify that the site certificate is valid (essentially a sub-case of point 3 in my original answer).

- [Comodo support: Untrusted Certificate Error on Android](https://support.comodo.com/index.php?/Default/Knowledgebase/Article/View/1019/1/untrusted-certificate-error-on-android)
- [certificate trusted on pc but not in android](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11340298/477035)
- [Comodo SSL Certificate showing as invalid on Android Devices](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/85409/8422)
- [How the Comodo certificate fraud calls CA trust into question](http://arstechnica.com/security/2011/03/how-the-comodo-certificate-fraud-calls-ca-trust-into-question/)

---

## NET::ERR CERT AUTHORITY INVALID

On later Android, there is a button on that dialog labeled "Advanced".

This gives you

> The server could not prove that it is www.redacted.ac.in, its security certificate is not trusted by your device's operating system. This may be caused by misconfiguration or an attacker intercepting your communication.

So either

- There is something wrong with the certificate (perhaps an untrustworthy CA)
- There is a device in the connection path that is substituting the certificate (sometimes the case with transparent proxy in an organisation's infrastructure)

## Comodo RSA

Your cert is issued by Commodo RSA

See [Commodo support](https://support.comodo.com/index.php?/Default/Knowledgebase/Article/View/1019/1/untrusted-certificate-error-on-android)

> The issue is that the Windows server is not presenting the complete certificate chain; clients which do not have the complete certificate chain will result in this error as encountered on the Android phone. In order to resolve this, on the server which this certificate is installed on, please open the MMC (Microsoft Management Console), and add the certificate snap-in for the computer account on the local computer.
>
> In the Intermediate Certification Authorities folder, verify if the Comodo RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA and Comodo RSA Certification Authority(issued to Comodo RSA Certification Authority, issued by AddTrustExternal CA Root) are installed in this certificate store.
>
> In the Trusted Root Certification Authorities folder verify if the AddTrustExternal CA Root is installed.  Also, if you see the Comodo RSA Certification Authority (issued to and issued by Comodo RSA Certification Authority with an expiration date of January 18, 2038) is present, if it is please delete this certificate.
>
> If any of these certificates are missing  the intermediate and root certificates were provided to you in the .zip file when the certificate was issued, or are available via this support article - https://support.comodo.com/index.php?/Default/Knowledgebase/Article/View/979/108/domain-validation-sha-2 .
>
> If you had to delete the Comodo RSA Certification Authority from the Trusted Root Authorities folder, you will also need to disable automatic root certificate updates on the server - https://support.comodo.com/index.php?/Default/Knowledgebase/Article/View/769/17/turn-off-automatic-root-certificates-updates-server-2008
>
> If you have performed these steps and the certificate chain has not updated on the server, to force IIS to update the certificate chain you will need to either change the certificate binding in IIS to another certificate, and then switch the certificate bindings to the correct certificate. Alternately, you will need to restart the server.

---

## Mixed Content

> **If we access the web site which is working on http as well as https using the correct certificate then we are getting SSL certificate warning error message.**

Browsers don't really like websites that mix HTTPS and HTTP content.

If, for example, the HTML is served by HTTPS but some images, scripts or CSS are served by HTTP, the browser cannot use the usual green-padlock to tell the user the website is secured. It is partially vulnerable.

See

- [Mozilla: Mixed content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Security/Mixed_content)
- [Mixed Content Blocking Enabled in Firefox 23!](https://blog.mozilla.org/tanvi/2013/04/10/mixed-content-blocking-enabled-in-firefox-23/)
- [Google: Fixing mixed content](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/security/prevent-mixed-content/fixing-mixed-content?hl=en)

---

## Other common certificate errors

> **It is working well for the web sites running only on http.**

No it isn't. For HTTP, the browser doesn't look at the certificate at all.

> **we are getting SSL certificate warning error message.**

The exact actual warning message will tell you what is wrong with the certificate. Some common problems include:

- it has expired.
- it is for a different domain than the website.
- the certificate issuer (CA) is not trusted by your browser.

The solutions are respectively

- renew it
- get a cert for the correct domain
- buy a cert from a different CA

---

Comment: It is valid certificate. Same certificate is working when we are using it in other sites which only run on http.

Comment: @1231: Please update your question with the exact message as displayed by the browser. If necessary, use an image editor to black out any sensitive parts. A certificate is for a domain. Different sites use different domain names.  foo.example.com and bar.example.com are different domain names.

Comment: Ok I will do it. Sorry it does not show any error for websites which is only using https

Comment: our certificate is wild card certificate. Certificate is for *.example. com.  This certificate is also for example.com. example. com is running with both http and https and getting this error. But others sites are not getting. Even if I host hello.example.com with http and https then also it shows the same warning error

Comment: @1231: See updated answer. I initially misunderstood your question.

Comment: Yes I have seen. In that case it has to show the mixed content warning. It is not that error. I will be posting the image of the error soon.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you are missing the intermediate certificates or the URL that you are going to doesn't match the common name of the certificate.

Comment: If it is the case then it should give the error for all the URLs.

Comment: This doesn't provide an answer to the original question and would be better suited to being a comment elsewhere. Please take the [tour] and read [answer] for more information.